# get first item on certain dropdown list and all from listbox using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form with number of dropdown list's and a listbox , at the end of the form is a "confirmation page", displaying all the data which was input.
The problem I am encountering is that the listbox allows the user to select a number of items
and when I implement the jquery to handle this, it applies to the dropdownbox also.

This results in the confirmation page displaying "1.Mr" instead of "Mr" from a dropdownbox of salutations for example.

But the listbox item display correctly, below is my jquery...

```
  var displayConfirm = function () {
            $('.display-value', form).each(function () {
                var input = $('[name="' + $(this).attr("data-display") + '"]',form);
                if (input.is(":text") || input.is("textarea")) {
                    $(this).text(input.val());
                } else if (input.is("select")) {
                    var html = '<ol>';
                    input.find('option:selected').each(function () {
                        html += '<li>' + $(this).text() + '</li>';
                    });
                    html += '</ol>';
                    $(this).html(html);
                }
            });
        };
```

is there a way of altering to include something like..

```
 else if (input.is("select") && input.val() < 1 ) {
```

Thanks

Comment: can you include a fiddle?

Comment: still learning, haven't used fiddle , can you explain steps?

Comment: go to jsFiddle.net. Put in your html and javascript that you have used in the respective sections. Save that fiddle and post the link here :)

Comment: You could check for the presence/value of the `size` attribute since this is what separates list boxes from drop down lists.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kD9Au/

Comment: @mkell don't use the mvc controls. Try and use the html derivatives

Comment: cheers asymptoticFault, could you until how that would look in code ?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but its an mvc application I'm working on, is it not good practice to use the mvc controllers ??

Comment: No no, that is not what I meant. What I meant was that in the fiddle you should use the html derivatives as fiddle cannot understand mvc controls. I have updated the fiddle. Can you just push in some data into the drop downs and then we can take it from there http://jsfiddle.net/kD9Au/2/

Comment: Maybe just add some class to your dropdown and check if this this input has this specific class.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kD9Au/4/ - hope thats what you ment ?

Comment: Also i think you have mispelled country

Comment: No it's meant to be counties , lets just role with it..

Comment: It is showing 1. because you have an ordered list (ol)

Comment: Yes, but I'd like to keep that ordered list as it display's my listItems in nice way....

Comment: Ok is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/kD9Au/5/

Comment: To check the `size` attribute I would think `if (input.attr('size') && parseInt(input.attr('size')) > 1)` should do the trick for checking if the select is a list box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Listbox helper is rendered as a `<select multiple="multiple">`. Hence, to select the right value, you have to check for the multiple attribute in the select tag that you find.

```
$(input.is('select')){
    if (input.attr('multiple') == "multiple") {
        var html = '<ol>';
        input.find('option:selected').each(function () {
            html += '<li>' + $(this).text() + '</li>';
        });
        html += '</ol>';
        $(this).html(html);
    } else {
        $(this).text(input.val())
    }
}
```

Ideally you can also lose the else condition and make it a more generic one where you don not check for any other type. So an updated version of code will look like this

```
if (input.is("select") && input.attr('multiple') == "multiple") {
    var html = '<ol>';
    input.find('option:selected').each(function () {
        html += '<li>' + $(this).text() + '</li>';
    });
    html += '</ol>';
    $(this).html(html);
} else {
    $(this).text(input.val());
}
```

You can find a working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kD9Au/6/).

Comment: If they're using the helpers, `ListBoxFor` will render the `multiple` attribute, whereas `DropDownListFor` will not.

Comment: Which is ok right? Just the DropDownList will render as a select and in that case it will be a single selection and hence no numbered list should be used. Whereas, in case of ListBox, there will be multiple selections and will render as select multiple and hence the check will read that data and render the selected values in an ordered list as required.

Comment: Oh yes this is fine, checking the `multiple` attribute is probably more reliable than checking the `size` attribute as I was thinking.  I was just pointing out in your answer that you were referring to the Web Forms `ListBox` which has the `SelectionMode` property and in MVC they should be using the helpers (not 100% clear on whether Web Forms controls will even work in MVC, and at the very least I do not think it is good practice).

Comment: I don't have so much experience in MVC, so I guessed that the properties must be the same :) Updated my answer. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Plugged code in to project and it works for the most part, but the ids are coming back instead of the names for the dropdowns where only one item can be selected, I believe the issue is with this line .... $(this).text(input.val());

Comment: Use the first solution and see if you get anything different

Comment: ok added a little to the statement and got displaying correctly...else if (input.is("select")) {
                        var html = '<span>';
                        input.find('option:selected').each(function () {
                            html += $(this).text();
                        });
                        html +='</span>'
                            $(this).html(html);
                        } Thanks for all your help...

Comment: But if it is a drop down, then there will be just one `option:selected`, so I think you can safely remove the each and it will still work. Also is there a way by which I can see it in action? I am pretty sure input.val() should work unless MVC does something more.